# Подключение к SQL Express LocalDB на другом ПК

Tags: c#, sql

При переносе БД на другой ПК возникает ошибка

Создал экземпляр из консоли

`sqllocaldb c MSSQLLocalDB`,

[image: Ошибка при запуске БД]

На основном ПК стоит версия 13.1.4001.0, при сборке установщик localDB ставится на другой ПК версия из моего проекта, но при проверке версий ставится 10.0.10586.

Как это исправить?

Comment: В вопросе нет главного: как именно происходит установка вашего приложения и СУБД. Однако, я догадываюсь, что используется Publish + Prerequsites. Верно?

Comment: [SqlLocalDB2016-Bootstrapper](https://github.com/igormf/SqlLocalDB2016-Bootstrapper) - опишите потом ощущения, как всё прошло.

Comment: Не знаю как проверить, виртуалка выключается на половине,  я   просто решил установить субд через exe, на другом ПК тип процессора не подходит. Но ощущения радости и слез.

Comment: Установка происходит через Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects, все что нужно скинул

Comment: Установил sql2016  на машине,
 sqllocaldb i MSSQLLocalDB (не видит)

Comment: _Установил sql2016_ - нет такой СУБД, вообще в природе не существует. У Sql Server есть разные версии, каждая с конкретным именем. Вот какую версию установили, к той и подключайтесь.

Comment: Установочник -> Необходимые компоненты -> Галочка на Fraemwork 4.6.1 & Sql Server 2012 Local DB

Comment: Проверяю версию на ПК 13, на машине 10

Comment: из за этого скорее всего вылезает данная ошибка

Comment: Не пишите в комментариях, их никто не видит. Отредактируйте вопрос, добавив туда всю необходимую информацию (как и что ставили). Вопрос поднимется на главную страницу сайта, его снова увидят.

Comment: _Галочка на ... Sql Server 2012 Local DB_ - я ссылку на бутстраппер давал - установите - должен появится пункт Sql Server 2016.